# Determining if a list is empty or not

Tags: list, prolog

I want to do some if | else stuff in prolog. Below is my code, Prolog will return 'R = false' if my input list is not empty, it will return 'false' if my list is empty. What do I miss?

Code:

```
isEmpty([H|T],R) :- 
    length([H|T],L),
    ( L > 0 -> R = 'false'
    ;
    L =:= 0 -> R = 'true'
    ).
```

Prolog Output:

```
1 ?- isEmpty([],R).
false.

2 ?- isEmpty([1],R).
R = false.

3 ?- isEmpty([1,2,3],R).
R = false.
```

Comment: Everything that **can** be handled by pattern matching **should** be handled by pattern matching. You do not need `if-then-else` at all to distinguish the cases.

Comment: Do note that in Prolog, it is rare to actually assign 'true' or 'false' to anything.  Much more common is to simply succeed, or to fail out.  So code: isEmpty([]).  would be the entire program.

Comment: @AlanBaljeu This means that anything that is not `[]` would be a non-empty list, which can be misleading: after all, we don't really know (from the question) how this is meant to be used, or how someone might decide to use it before realizing what it _actually_ means.

Comment: I really don't see what you mean by misleading.  Assuming this should only be used for lists, [] is empty, and anything else is not.  Who would use a method called isEmpty() without knowing what it's talking about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to define this would be to use unification ("pattern matching"):

```
list_empty([], true).
list_empty([_|_], false).
```

If you insist on using an if-then-else, you need to pass the list *without trying to match it in any way*:

```
list_zerolength(List, Empty) :-
    length(List, Len),
    (   Len == 0
    ->  Empty = true
    ;   Empty = false
    ).
```

... but this is not optimal. The two predicates behave identically if the first argument is indeed a list:

```
?- list_empty([], R).
R = true.

?- list_empty([_], R).
R = false.

?- list_zerolength([], R).
R = true.

?- list_zerolength([_], R).
R = false.
```

However, something annoying happens if the first argument is not *ground* (that is, is not fully instantiated):

```
?- list_zerolength(L, true).
L = [] ;
ERROR: Out of global stack
```

So, we try to ask for an empty list, and we get it; however, Prolog insists there might be another answer. When we try to get it, we get an error.

(Extra credit: figure out what happens!)

The predicate `list_empty/2` is not perfect, either. Consider:

```
?- list_empty([_|a], R).
R = false.
```

This succeeds, and we could interpret the answer as: "The list `[_|a]` is not empty". However, this is not ever a [proper list](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=is_list/1)!

```
?- is_list([_|a]).
false.
```

Using `length/2` is not at all a bad idea. We can use it to write a predicate that is arguably a bit more useful than `list_empty/2`. I call it `list_nonempty/2` to confuse the situation:

```
list_nonempty([], false).
list_nonempty([_|T], true) :-
    length(T, _).
```

`length/2` does a lot more than just finding the length of a list. It can be used to generate lists of increasing length, or check whether its first argument is a proper list:

```
?- list_nonempty(L, NE).
L = [],
NE = false ;
L = [_G904],
NE = true ;
L = [_G904, _G907],
NE = true . % and so on

?- list_nonempty(L, false).
L = [].

?- list_nonempty([], true).
false.

?- list_nonempty([_|a], true).
ERROR: length/2: Type error: `list' expected, found `a' (an atom)
```

SWI-Prolog throws an error when `length/2` is not given a list. Implementations that are more committed to ISO-compliance should fail instead. With GNU Prolog:

```
?- list_nonempty([_|a], true).    
no
```

Comment: Maybe elaborate on the problems?

Comment: @false I wanted to take a 15 min break and thought this is an easy enough question. I knew I would be called out on it. I will try to elaborate.

Comment: @false I did indeed go into more detail. I wonder if this is any better than it was before.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's old thread but still this might be useful for those using SWI-Prolog. Instead of defining their own rules, you can try:

```
nth0(0, List, _).
```

It is used to return the first element on the list, which in case of empty list simply fails.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are only dealing with lists of the form `[H|T]` your clauses will only match for lists that have at least one list element.  In other words, you get the answer `false` for the empty list because there is not a matching clause - not because the length is 0.