# Deterministically finding last element of a list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Finding the last element of a list in Prolog seems to be straightforward

```
my_last([A], A).
my_last([_,A|T], E) :-
    my_last([A|T], E).
```

Unfortunately, this predicate is non-deterministic, no matter how "instantiated" the actual parameters are.

```
?- my_last([1,2,3], 3).
true ;
false.
```

Looking at the implementation of the `nth0/3` here https://github.com/mthom/scryer-prolog/blob/master/src/lib/lists.pl, there's a "trick" to guard the actual predicates with `integer(N) ->` which acts like a preprocessor and splits the predicate into a deterministic and a non-deterministic branches.

So how do I define such preprocessor conditions for `my_last/2`, in order to make it deterministic for the case where the tail of the list is not a variable? Can it be done efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can see swi-prolog's code:

```
?- listing(last).
lists:last([X|Xs], Last) :-
    last_(Xs, X, Last).

?- listing(last_).
lists:last_([], Last, Last).
lists:last_([X|Xs], _, Last) :-
    last_(Xs, X, Last).
```

This is using empty list `[]` vs head-and-tail `[Head|Tail]` distinction in the first argument, to be deterministic. More info at [Determining if a list is empty or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35484964/determining-if-a-list-is-empty-or-not)